# How to know if a Jenkins job has been triggered by another Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins

Using Jenkins plugin [Jenkins Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin), is there a way to identify in the triggered job the triggering job?

Note: I added a build parameter with hardcoded JobId, but I do not think this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there are two questions:

1. "*How to know if a Jenkins job has been triggered by another Jenkins job?*
   " - the triggered job has an environment variable `${BUILD_CAUSE}` - if that's equal to `UPSTREAMTRIGGER` that means the job was triggered by an upstream job
2. "*is there a way to identify in the triggered job the triggering job?*" - not sure if there is any better way, but in the triggering job you can save the ENV VAR ${JOB_NAME} and then pass that as a parameter to the next job. So let's say I have two jobs `quick_test1` and `quick_test2` and the first is triggering the second, and I want to know the name of the triggering job. The job 1 will be configured as follows:

[image]

The second job needs the parameter as follows:

[image]

You can then `echo ${VAR1}` in the second job to see the name of the first job.